# C# unit testing: simulate SD card

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sd-card

I write an application in C# that performs tasks when a SD card is mounted or unmounted.
It acts on DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE messages.
Now I want to write tests that check if the application reacts correctly on these events.
How can I simulate the arrival and removal of an SD card in a Unit Test?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to show us your actual code otherwise anyone who attempts an answer is literally guessing to be honest, typically you would abstract out the "SD CARD" specific functionality and simply test the methods that handle the events.

Comment: Put the code triggering the event into a class implementing an interface then code against the interface. Mock out the interface in the unit test (or create a dummy class).

Comment: That can be a partial solution, though my code gets device label and serial number and all that will have to be mocked too. I would like a solution where I have a known SD card in my computer and be able to mount/unmount it from my unit test to test application response.

Comment: Unit tests should not rely on external factors like physically removing a card.  That makes them integration tests, which are important, but serve a different purpose.

Comment: Ok so then I should have used the term "integration tests" in my title ;-)

Comment: Please show is some code, there is nothing anyone can do to help you specifically until then.

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper around the SD card framework code, extract an interface and develop your code against that interface. Yes, you'll have to mock everything then, but that's the clean way to go. Keep in mind that you don't have to use a mocking library like `Rhino.Mocks` for your tests (people tend to forget). Sometimes writing a specialized fake object for your tests makes testing easier.

Writing a test that only passes when a known SD card is mounted, is not a unit test.